# Что такое activity в Linux?

Tags: linux, терминология

Периодически сталкиваюсь с этим термином, но все никак не пойму что это, какой-то концепт, связанный с процессами, и видимо не в одном только линуксе, но и других ОСях.
Скажем, на рабочем столе в KDE у меня есть кнопка "Новое Activity".
В тематике Android так же порой проскакивает что нибудь, например "жизненный цикл activity".
В интернетах что-то никак не найду объяснения.

Comment: Скажем, на рабочем столе в KDE у меня есть кнопка "Новое Activity".  

В тематике Android так же порой проскакивает что нибудь, например "жизненный цикл activity".

Comment: В разных контекстах это разные вещи, связанные с kde и с android соответственно, а линукс тут ни при чём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это термин из KDE. На русский язык переведено крайне неудачно (IMHO) словом "Комната". Имеет смысл - совокупность видов деятельности (Activity), близких по смыслу, цели и т.д.

Например, на своём OpenSuse я организовал 4 комнаты (видов активности):

1. Оффис
2. Интернет
3. Графика
4. Разработка

Каждая комната/активность имеет свой рабочий стол. Например, в комнате "Графика", в качестве обоев используется фотография моего  любимого фотоаппарата :-) "Интернет" - паутина и т.д.

Аналогично, в каждой комнате свой набор иконок на столе, наиболее подходящий для этого вида активности.

В принципе - довольно удобно. Мне становится приятно, когда я вижу, что у поклонников виндовоза рабочий стол загажен иконками так, что сам чёрт ногу сломит :-)

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ. Замечу, правда, что в 10 реализованы виртуальные рабочие столы со своими бледжеком и окнами.

Comment: **в 10 реализованы виртуальные рабочие столы** - возможно. Но у меня это было 5 лет назад и бесплатно...

Comment: Ну, положим, я и семь лет назад ставил себе приложение на винду, которое их создавало. Не скажу, что пользовался им, но возможность была. В общем, я не предлагаю открывать холивар Winda vs Linux, просто отмечу что как по мне, для домашнего пользования она куда лучше подходит. Но это сугубо моё мнение.